# How often do MXLogic lists get updated?

Tags: smtp, spam, spam-filter, rbl

Some domain refused to accept email from my domain due to MXLogic filtering.

I've sent an email to `falsepositives@mxlogic.com` and they responded promptly that they changed their records.

Question: how long does it take for MXLogic subscriber to receive the updated filtering lists? Are they doing updates once an hour, a day or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MX Logic is now a McAfee SaaS service](http://www.mxlogic.com/). As a cloud-based service, it should be updated for all of their subscribers as soon as McAfee makes the changes, give or take a few minutes. If you want an exact number, you can always contact McAfee and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

We distribute the MX Logic /McAfee SaaS email product in Australia & New Zealand.As a 100% cloud filtering service it is literally updated in real time. From an AV perspective, perspective updates are received in real time from McAfee, Sophos and Authentium. From an anti-spam and breaking threats there is a room of 5 full time threat techs, and 4 developers (who write scripts for the threat techs) in Englewood, Colorado who's entire role is to continuously update the MX logic rules to better stop the bad stuff, and let the good stuff through. This, on top of all the inputs from McAfee's Global Threat Intelligence and various other global sources.

Hope this helps :)

Cheers,

Andrew Johnson, Manage Protect www.manageprotect.com